# Hashi vault - how to get x-vault-token to get secret id using role id?

Tags: hashicorp-vault

I am able to do the following using `CLI`.

```
// Get role id
vault read auth/approle/role/irma-role/role-id
    Key     Value
    role_id b1e32157-8309-d5a2-02c9-657fc05977dc

// Get secret id
vault write -force auth/approle/role/irma-role/secret-id
    Key                Value                               
    secret_id          3cac8255-6f2d-e62f-fd0e-20bfe69a2dfe
    secret_id_accessor 8f811a56-d2c4-460c-8955-f2a18d8a2fdd

// Login using role id and secret id
vault write auth/approle/login role_id="b1e32157-8309-d5a2-02c9-657fc05977dc" secret_id="ea34790f-f8c4-5527-3951-4e51b8b6e620"
```

The above works great. But I need help in figuring out how to do using API. For example, how to I get the `X-Vault-Token` that the API is looking for while retrieving secret id?

```
$ curl \
    --header "X-Vault-Token: ..." \
    --request POST \
    http://127.0.0.1:8200/v1/auth/approle/role/application1/secret-id
```

Comment: Added multiple code blocks in order to improve readability.

Comment: teh token should be returned form this command `vault write auth/approle/login role_id="b1e32157-8309-d5a2-02c9-657fc05977dc" secret_id="ea34790f-f8c4-5527-3951-4e51b8b6e620"`

Comment: If you want the exact same token that you are using when you use the CLI, you can see it in either the env var `VAULT_TOKEN` or the file `~/.vault-token`. Alternatively you can just run `vault token lookup` and it will show you the details of the token. The token itself appears as the `id` field.